# Java How To Find Class? (Attempting to load the driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)

Tags: java, mysql, class, jdbc, classloader

I am trying to use [adit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adit/?source=typ_redirect) in my local environment.

I copied the files to:

```
/Users/koraytugay/adit-0.93
```

I go to terminal and type:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/koraytugay/adit-0.93/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar
```

I am sure that .jar file is there.

Then I type:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:adit-0.93 koraytugay$ java -jar adit.jar
```

However I am constantly getting:

```
Attempting to load the driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Driver not found
SQL Exeception: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebtam
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `-jar`, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is ignored.

The simplest approach here would probably be to use:

```
java -cp adit.jar:/Users/koraytugay/adit-0.93/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar foo.bar.MyMainClass
```

Alternatively, you can specify relative classpath entries to a jar file [via the manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html). So you could have:

```
Class-Path: mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar
```

in the manifest, and copy that jar file into the same directory as `adit.jar`, then you should be able to use `-jar`.